# Unable to load Windows Universal Sample projects

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app

I was trying to run a Windows Universal Sample project from this location

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

Specifically the sample called XamlContextMenu.

However in Visual Studio I keep getting this error

[image]

The message points me to this page

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

But there is no emulator posted with that version number.  I installed both of the ones listed on the page, but it still presents the same message.

**EDIT** after installing VS 2015 Update 2 I was able to load the project.  But then I was trying to load another project and the same thing happened, but it complain about a different version

[image]

The project was this one

https://github.com/jamesqquick/Win10Universal

And the error message (Install) link points me to this page
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn975273.aspx

Which I think is the wrong page

As far as I know I have the latest Visual studio, all updated installed.  All I want to do is try these projects which were built prior to the latest updates I installed.

Why are there these problems opening projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your development system navigate to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs

Choose the folder for which you are developing app for example `WindowsDesktop`. Usually the subfolders are supposed to be same for all platform. This number represents the latest windows version installed on your system. Note it down.
Now inside visual studio on your project right click and click on **Edit YourProject.csproj**
Now here look for

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10240.0" />
```

You will need to update this to the version numbers here to ones that is installed on your system especially the minversion number.
Now save it and you should be able to open up your project in most of the cases.

Comment: I was only able to find these two entry <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10030.0</TargetPlatformVersion><TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10030.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>

Comment: Yes you need to change them on my dev system I changed them to   <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion> and now am able to open it up. Pls check your system version and update accordingly

Comment: Great nice to hear that.